# Proof for hamiltonian cyclein grids having even no. of nodes

Tags: algorithm, graph, hamiltonian-cycle

How can I go about proving that an undirected graph having even no. of nodes (at least one of the rows or columns are even - excluding line graphs of course) have a hamiltonian cycle?

I have  managed to come as far as to prove that it is a bipartite graph and (as a result ) has all cycles of even length.

But exactly how can I show that at least one such cycle exists that covers all the available nodes?

Comment: Can't you just snake back and forth across the rows to get a Hamiltonian path?

Comment: @templatetypedef : Yes I can do that. But I want a general proof for ANY grid.